# Python - Conditional statement not working while extracting data from a column in a spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, colors, conditional-statements, openpyxl

I have two Excel files:

1. Stock_ex2.xlsx with three columns [Item, Quantity, Price)
   This file is filled with data up to 50 rows. Row 1 is the header
2. UpdatedStock_ex2.xlsx
   This is file is empty

The program below, copies data from Stock_ex2 file to UpdatedStock_ex2 file.
It then searches for the word "Price". I need to know the address / column / cell name. It works fine till here:

The problem is with the 'If' statement i.e. I want to color code the cells where the Price is less than 100. It does not happen nor does it show anything in the file. It works without 'If'. But i need this 'If'. Can you please assist? Thanks!

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\Ricky\\Desktop\\Stock_ex2.xlsx")
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\Ricky\\Desktop\\UpdatedStock_ex2.xlsx")

print(wb.sheetnames)
wb1['Sheet1'].title="Copied Info"
print(wb1.sheetnames)
sh1 = wb.active
sh2 = wb1.active
print(sh1)
print(sh2)
row1=sh1.max_row
col1=sh1.max_column
print(f'#of rows: {row1}')
print(f'# of columns: {col1}')

for i in range (1,row1+1): #Copies info from one sheet of a file to another file
    for j in range (1, col1+1):
        sh2.cell(row=i,column=j).value = sh1.cell(row=i,column=j).value


for row in sh2.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "Price":
                print(cell.row,cell.column) #Prints row #, col #
                print(cell.coordinate) #Prints the actual address of the cell i.e.C1
                print(cell.value) #Prints Price

for cell in sh2['C2':'C50']: #Using C column from the above info as Price can be in any column
    if sh2.cell.value < 100:
        sh2.cell.fill = PatternFill("solid",fgColor="71FF35")
print("Color Complete")
   
wb1.save("C:\\Users\\Ricky\\Desktop\\UpdatedStock_ex2.xlsx")
print("file Saved")
```

Comment: maybe use `print()` to see values in viariables - maybe they are different then you expect and `if` can't be executed.

Comment: tried print() already. It does not enter the for loop for picking values less than 100

Comment: if it doesn't enter `for`-loop then check `print( sh2['C2':'C50'] )`

Comment: ofcourse tried to it with print. It does not enter the loop

Comment: did you try `print( sh2['C2':'C50'] )` before `for` loop ? You can also check `print( print(len( sh2['C2':'C50'] ) )`. maybe it gives empty list and then it will not run `for`-loop

Comment: Not sure how will print( sh2['C2':'C50'] ) before the for loop help solve the problem ??All it will do is give values of "Copied Indo >C2". As far as print( print(len( sh2['C2':'C50'] ) )  is concerned, it will print the length of the column and give 49. Not udseful. This is not the objective of the program nor does it help in solve the problem.

Comment: it shows what you have in `sh2['C2':'C50']` - you may have different value then you expect and then `for`-loop may works in different way then you expect. It is called `debuging`. Your prints shows me that problem is not in this place. I don't have your full code and I can run it to debug it - so you have to do it and show what you get. If `len()` gives 49 then it should enter this loop and it should `print(sh2.cell.value)` before `if`

Comment: BUT now I see other strange thing - you assign values from `sh2['C2':'C50']` to variable `cell` (using `for cell in sh2['C2':'C50']:`) but later you use `sh2.cell.value` instead of `cell.value`  - so you compare always the same `sh2.cell.value < 100` instead of `cell.value < 100` .